# Are permutation matrices over reals reductive?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

**Question**

Let $H$ denote the subgroup of permutation matrices of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$. Is $H$ a reductive group?

**My Work**

I know that $H$ is a linear algebraic group being a finite subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$. And, I have found various facts saying that the permutation matrices as an algebraic subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ is reductive, e.g.,

> Symmetric subgroups of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ are linearly
>   reductive and being linearly reductive is equivalent to being
>   reductive over algebraically closed fields of zero characteristic.

I have tried to apply the following facts to this problem but have not had success:

> 1. A linear algebraic group over a field of characteristic $0$ is reductive if and only if its Lie algebra is a reductive Lie algebra.
> 2. Let $G$ be a reductive group and $H$ a closed subgroup, then the $H$ is reductive if and only if the quotient space $G/H$ is affine.

I have primarily tried applying fact (2) above, since $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is a reductive group and the subgroup of permutation matrices is a closed subgroup. But, I am unable to determine whether $G/H$ is affine.

**Motivation**

I am curious about this question because I have a real algebraic variety with a group action on it by real permutation matrices, and I am curious about applying techniques of Geometric Invariant Theory to this problem. I do not know a lot about GIT, but from I have read one gets nice statements statements when the group is algebraic and reductive, hence my question.

Comment: As you say, $H$ is a **finite** group.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I could not find a reference for the statement that every finite group is reductive when I was reading about them. Is it just a simple exercise, or would you be able to point me towards a reference for that statement - even an exercise in a book would suffice? Thank you.

Comment: See your comment 1.

Comment: Which definition would you like to use? Note that most nice results about algebraic group actions require it to be connected in order for the geometric structure to have much use.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I was originally thinking along the lines of `linearly reductive if every rational representation of $G$ is completely reducible'. Mumford says that in characteristic $0$ this is equivalent to a linear algebraic group being reductive if the radical of $G$ is a torus. It seems like this might imply a connectedness condition on $G$, and so maybe my question is ill-posed. Thank you for pointing that out about the group needing to be connected for nice applications.

Comment: Note that being reductive by definition is a statement about a maximal solvable *connected* normal subgroup. This makes it very easy to show that this is a reductive group.